Is there such a thing as "Syrian literature"?
Mohja Kahf's 2001 article "The silences of contemporary Syrian literature" opens as follows:

There is, of course, no such thing as Syrian literature. Certainly, citizens of the modern nation-state of Syria write literature, but to claim that "Syrian literature" exists in the same way that, say, Russian literature or German literature exists is misleading. First, it implies that there is a language called Syrian. Syrian literature is, for the most part, written in Arabic and is part of a literary family that includes all literature written in Arabic. Second, anyone familiar with the Middle East will be quick to point out that "Syria" itself is a complicated label. From ancient times until the early twentieth century, the term has been used loosely ...

Later in the same article:

It is helpful, here, to point briefly to Egyptian, Palestinian, and Lebanese literatures by comparison. As in the Syrian case, each of these literatures is intrinsically part of the Arabic cultural world. Yet no one disputes the fact that "modern Egyptian literature" makes sense as a category [...] Geography gives Egypt cohesiveness. Modern Palestinian literature coheres around the catastrophic wrenching of the Palestinian people from their historical homeland in 1948. Having a literature is crucial to the survival of this uprooted and embattled community. Or, take Lebanese literature today: the prolonged civil war of 1975-90 wounded Lebanon, and the wound became a well of words.' Syria lacks the geographic cohesiveness of Egypt and has been spared the Palestinian and the Lebanese traumas. Nevertheless, it does enrich our understanding to bundle together the literature of Syria; such a harvesting allows us to become aware of patterns and to experience esthetic pleasures otherwise undetectable. That may be the only good reason - and it is a sufficient one -- to endeavor theorizing Syrian literature.

The paper continues by discussing "Syrian literature", some common features in this bundle and some attempts to define its boundaries and so on, despite the author's earlier claim that there is "no such thing as Syrian literature". My question is, has scholarly thinking on this issue changed since 2001? Obviously, the situation of Syria has drastically changed since then, and it no longer makes sense to say that Syria "has been spared the Palestinian and the Lebanese traumas". Is there now generally considered to be a cohesive "Syrian literature", or is Kahf's opening sentence still held to be valid by experts in the field?

At least a partial answer may be found in this 2013 article, and perhaps this 2022 article may also be relevant.

In order to answer the question of whether his statement is still held to be valid, can you provide some evidence of his reception by scholars 20 years ago?
